# Batch Update (Error Code 0x81020016)

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list, innerxml

I have used webservices to Update Sharepoint list. I am using Network Credentials to access remort server.

```
mylist.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password, _domain);
```

here is my innerXml code:

```
       StringBuilder innerXml = new StringBuilder();
              innerXml.AppendFormat("<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
              "<Field Name='ID'>" + id + "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='Title'>" + title + "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='CostCTRShortText'>" + CostCTRShortText + "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='ActTyp'>" + ActTyp + "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='Employee'>" + Employee + "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='Price'>" + Price + "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='ITECCategory'>" + ITECCategory + "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='ServicePrice'>" + ServicePrice + "</Field>"
              );

        innerXml.AppendLine("</Method>");
```

Unfortunatly I am geting an error when Update:

```
<Result ID="1,Update" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><ErrorCode>0x81020016</ErrorCode><ErrorText>Item does not exist

The page you selected contains an item that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.</ErrorText></Result>
```

This is only occur when Im trying to update List item in Remote server. Same code will work and update list item in Local site as expected.

Please help me.

Comment: The error message is telling you you're trying to update a list item that does not exist. Have you double-checked that the ID you're referencing actually does exist in the list on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. Here `ID` is playing important roll. Make sure that your `ID` field retrieve the correct value. In my case ,My local list starts form ID =1 but production server list has not a row which ID=1 .

You can simply visible this ID column from your SharePoint list. And check the value.